# Ajax partial update via asp:UpdatePanel postback is safe?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I was wondering whether in ASP.NET, using the asp:UpdatePanel and have a postbacktrigger or asyncpostbacktrigger, is it safe? E.g. if I have some data in textbox that need to use either 1 of the postback trigger, will the data be visible (safe)??

Answer (score 0):

It won't be any different than a standard request back to the server; it will just appear to the user that the page isn't posting back, even though the update panel posts the full viewstate and the form...

So the data will just be as "visible" as a standard post to the server is.